# How to change button text with spinner in ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I need to to change button text with font awesome spinner on ng-click function.

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="{{buttonText}}"  ng-click="Save()" />
```

My Script as

```
app.controller("CateCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.buttonText = 'Save';
    $scope.Save = function () {
           $scope.buttonText = '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i> Please wait';
        }); 
    });
```

It change the text as it is ` Please wait

Not showing spinner icon.`

Answer (score 1):

use ng-class

```
<button><i ng-class="{'fa fa-spinner fa-pulse' : loading}"></i></button>
```

On the click of the button set

```
    app.controller("CateCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
       $scope.buttonText = 'Save';
       $scope.Save = function () {
          $scope.loading = true;
       }); 
   });
```

Edit1: You can have html inside your button tag. [Read](http://web.archive.org/web/20110721191046/http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, using `ng-if` condition.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<button>
  <i ng-click="Save()" ng-if="loading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>
  <span ng-click="Save()" ng-if="!loading">Save</span>
</button>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    
       $scope.Save = function () {
          $scope.loading = !$scope.loading;
       }; 
    
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/PvmcdvpBxrJR0HPGxhSx?p=preview)

Comment: You can take it another step, but disabling the button with `ng-disable="loading"` so that the user can't click on the button multiple times